# perl reference hash with two similar words not all counted

Tags: database, perl, hash, reference

I am writing a Perl project and am facing the problem as followed:
I have a large input file which has a comment file and a revenue field. The comment field could have DTN or Cluster Master DTN and both would have revenue of 300 to be counted into their own category. 
The following is part of the code:

```
elsif ($comments == /DTN/i and $revenue == 300)
{
    $class = 'DTN';
}

elsif ($revenue == 300)
{
    if ($comments =~ /cluster master\+DTN/i)
    {
        $class = 'SLA Cluster Master + DTN';
    }
    elsif ($comments =~ /cluster master and DTN/i)
    {   
        $class = 'SLA Cluster Master + DTN';
    }
}
```

In the output tho, it counts the number of revenue that is 300 to be the number of DTN field and it only counts the comments of 'cluster master+DTN'  as the SLA Cluster Master + DTN instead of 'cluster master and DTN' which should also be counted in. 
I have no idea what's going on and how to fix the problem. Is there anybody else having the same problem?

Comment: Your logic doesn't make any sense.  Assuming you fix the `==` to `=~` on the first line, your first elsif is catching cases where both `$comments` contains 'DTN' and `$revenue` is 300.  For this to be skipped and the next elsif to be executed, one of those two conditions has to be false.  The 2nd elsif again checks for `$revenue` equal to 300.  If that's true, it must mean that `$comments` does not contain 'DTN'.  But then both of your two clauses within the second elsif are checking to see that `$comments` contains (other text and) 'DTN'.  Those two blocks will never be hit.

Comment: @PaulL Thanks so much. It was the logic problem that causes the wrong output! You are awesome

Answer (score 2):

The first 
`elsif ($comments == /DTN/i and $revenue == 300)` is all wrong.

You want `elsif ($comments =~ /DTN/i and $revenue == 300)`

or I suspect probably actually you want `elsif ($comments =~ /^DTN$/i and $revenue == 300)` to give you an exact match, not a match anywhere in the $comments string because without that, you'll never hit the `$class=` statements below.

Comment: So /^DTN$/i means exactly matches and case insensitive?
I tried it but still the output counts are the number of revenues that are 300 ignoring the comments fields

Comment: Yes. '^' means beginning of the string and '$' means the end. Without the full script or the input, and expected output, there's only so much we can do.